# Having trouble selecting checkboxes

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, nightwatch

The checkbox on my page looks like this:

```html
<td role="gridcell" style="width: 30px; padding:0;text-align: center;" class="ui-selection-column">
  <div class="ui-chkbox ui-widget">
    <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"><input type="checkbox" name="dataTable_checkbox" aria-checked="false"></div>
    <div class="ui-chkbox-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default"><span class="ui-chkbox-icon ui-icon ui-c ui-icon-blank"></span></div>
  </div>
</td>
```

It's contained in a tbody and tr data.

I'm trying to select it by using

```
.click('input[id="ui-chkbox ui-widget", type="checkbox"]')
```

And I already tried using .waitForElementVisible and still couldn't select it.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "select it"? Are you trying to *find* the element or are you trying to mark the input as 'checked'?

Comment: I'm trying to mark the input as checked. Sorry.

Comment: I've only just noticed the 'automated-test' and 'nightwatch' tags. Its not at all clear from your question that what you're actually trying to do is trigger a click event in Nightwatch.js. Your id is wrong but I suspect that `.click('input[name="dataTable_checkbox"]')` will work.

Comment: That also doesn't work. My checkboxes are separated by rows in a table, so every one of them has the same name, but they are in different rows. I don't know how to select a checkbox IN a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per your code here:

```
.click('input[id="ui-chkbox ui-widget", type="checkbox"]')
```

You are mistakenly identifying the classes `ui-chkbox ui-widget` as an id. Find the specific id on the page for that checkbox, if there is one, and select it using that. IDs on a page are specific to that element.

```
.click('#youridhere')
```

Alternatively, use Xpath and select it by its path containing any text.

```
.click("//*[contains(text(), 'Checkbox text here')]")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't select it because you do not have an `input` field with `id` as ui-chkbox ui-widget:

As per your code below:

```html
<td role="gridcell" style="width: 30px; padding:0;text-align: center;" class="ui-selection-column">
  <div class="ui-chkbox ui-widget">
    <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
      <input type="checkbox" name="dataTable_checkbox" aria-checked="false">
    </div>
    <div class="ui-chkbox-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default">
      <span class="ui-chkbox-icon ui-icon ui-c ui-icon-blank"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
```

You should use checkbox name in selector

```
 input:checkbox[name='dataTable_checkbox']
```

OR

```
input[type='checkbox'][name='dataTable_checkbox']
```

OR

```
input[type='checkbox', name='dataTable_checkbox']
```

Comment: Got multiple " Error while running .locateMultipleElements() protocol action: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified" errors and after that, an "  NoSuchElementError: An error occurred while running .click() command on <input[type="checkbox", name="dataTable_checkbox"]>:". Did I do it right or is it missing something?

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who's whondering on how to select a checkbox in a table, I found a method that works just fine: When you inspect an element, right click on it > copy > copy selector. Paste it with .click ('yourselectorhere') and it should run just fine. Worked for me.